# Drupal 7 Adjustable css

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, theming

i'm making a cms for a news site and i'm stuck with something my customer asked me to do. 
He wants to give an article a ranking of importance. The most important article has to be on top, bigger and with more "bling" (css) ... Is there a possible way to adjust CSS due to a given value on a specific content type.

Kind regards
Designosource

Comment: Please show some code or and image what exactly you want to achieve. so we can help you and understand your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1) You state the article will be on top, so that implies to me that it will be the first article on the page. If so, then depending on how your articles are targeted, something like `.article:first-child` (CSS2, the element must be the first in its container) or `.article:first-of-type` (CSS3, the element must be the first of its type [div, span, etc.] in its container) would work to specifically target that important article.

2) Since it is a dynamic (drupal) site, then nothing should prevent you from just having drupal evaluate the article importance and then put a class like `.prominent` on the element for that article and targeting all your special css to that class.

Answer (score 0):

Scotts is correct.  Use the Views module to sort the content the way you would like it too display and use jQuery to apply dynamic classes to the content.  For example if it were a list of items in a block you could do this with jQuery.

```
$('.block .content ul li').each(function(e){
    $(this).addClass('importance' + e);
});


.importance0 { font-size: 18px; }
.importance1 { font-size: 14px }
.importance2 { font-size: 12px }
```

Checkout the weight module to give weight per node: http://drupal.org/project/weight